# What does the \usepackage {nimbusmononarrow} command do?

Tags: fonts, packages, typography

I know what the command `\usepackage{}` does but I don't know what kind of package `nimbusmononarrow`is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/nimbus15mononarrow/. It is a font, monospaced, a narrow version of the nimbus 15 font, available from the TeX User Group (TUG).

Depending on whether `\familydefault` is renewed or not, it will be available as the `\texttt`/`\ttfamily` font, or as the default document font.

[image]

Note: Danish not required.